# What happens after an iPhone has its data auto-erased?

Tags: iphone, backup, security

On the "Touch ID & Passcode", there's the option "Erase Data", which says

> Erase all data on this iPhone after 10 failed passcode attempts.
>
> Data protection is enabled.

Is it possible to restore the phone using a laptop that has backed up the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once erased by the failed passcode attempts, the phone will be put in [Activation Lock](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365) (assuming you have iOS 7 or later and have enabled Find My iPhone). You will need to unlock it using the Apple ID it is linked to. From there, you can restore the phone from a previous backup.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. you can restore it. there're many software that can scan your iPhone and lost all your data deleted or existing on your iPhone, you can preview and find if there are the files that you want to recover.

Comment: You can't recover data from a locked/disabled iPhone (unless you had the data backed up).